# Multi threaded C program freezes when I change number of threads

Tags: c, gcc, pthreads

I am writing a multi threaded c program to multiply two matrices and find the row norm using pthreads and Blas. I thought I had it working when I set the dimension of the matrices to 4 and the number of threads to use to 2. I then changed the number of threads, and it no longer works. It does not compute the wrong answers, but gets stuck when I try to join the threads

```
void *matrix_norm(void *arg){
    mat_norm_t *thread_mat_norm_data = arg;
    int n = thread_mat_norm_data->n;
    int i, j;
    double norm = 0.;

    for(i=0;i<thread_mat_norm_data->sub_n;i++){
        double row_sum = 0.;
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            row_sum += *(thread_mat_norm_data->z+i*n+j);
        }
        if(row_sum>norm){
            norm = row_sum;
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(thread_mat_norm_data->mutex);
    if (norm > *(thread_mat_norm_data->global_norm)){
        *(thread_mat_norm_data->global_norm)=norm;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(thread_mat_norm_data->mutex);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
    pthread_t *working_thread;
    mat_mult_t *thread_mat_mult_data;
    mat_norm_t *thread_mat_norm_data;
    pthread_mutex_t *mutex;
    double *x, *y, *z, norm;
    int i, rows_per_thread;

    int n = 8;  
    int num_of_thrds = 4;// Works when this is 2, not when 4 

    if(n<=num_of_thrds && num_of_thrds < MAXTHRDS){
        printf("Matrix dim must be greater than num of thrds\nand num of thrds less than 124.\n");
        return (-1);
    }

    x = malloc(n*n*sizeof(double));
    y = malloc(n*n*sizeof(double));  
    z = malloc(n*n*sizeof(double));
    initMat(n, x);
    initMat(n, y);

    working_thread = malloc(num_of_thrds * sizeof(pthread_t));
    thread_mat_mult_data = malloc(num_of_thrds * sizeof(mat_mult_t));
    rows_per_thread = n/num_of_thrds;

    for(i=0;i<num_of_thrds;i++){
        thread_mat_mult_data[i].x = x + i * rows_per_thread * n;
        thread_mat_mult_data[i].y = y;
        thread_mat_mult_data[i].z = z + i * rows_per_thread * n;
        thread_mat_mult_data[i].n = n;
        thread_mat_mult_data[i].sub_n = 
             (i == num_of_thrds-1) ? n-(num_of_thrds-1)*rows_per_thread : rows_per_thread;
        pthread_create(&working_thread[i], NULL, matrix_mult, (void *)&thread_mat_mult_data[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<num_of_thrds;i++){
        pthread_join(working_thread[i], NULL);
    }
    free(working_thread);

    working_thread = malloc(num_of_thrds * sizeof(pthread_t));
    thread_mat_norm_data = malloc(num_of_thrds * sizeof(mat_norm_t));
    mutex = malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));

    for(i=0;i<num_of_thrds;i++){
        thread_mat_norm_data[i].z = z + i * rows_per_thread * n;
        thread_mat_norm_data[i].n = n;
        thread_mat_norm_data[i].global_norm = &norm;
        thread_mat_norm_data[i].sub_n = 
           (i == num_of_thrds-1) ? n-(num_of_thrds-1)*rows_per_thread : rows_per_thread;
        thread_mat_norm_data[i].mutex = mutex;
        pthread_create(&working_thread[i], NULL, matrix_norm, (void *)&thread_mat_norm_data[i]);
    }
    //Stuck running here
    for(i=0;i<num_of_thrds;i++){
        pthread_join(working_thread[i], NULL);
    }

    printMat(n, z , "z");
    printf("\nRow Sum Norm = %f\n", norm);


    free(x);    
    free(y);   
    free(z);       
    free(working_thread);
    free(thread_mat_mult_data);
    free(thread_mat_norm_data);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(mutex);
    free(mutex);

    return(0);
}
```

I unsure why it works under certain circumstances and not others, any explanation would be great!

Comment: You know `stdout` is probably line-buffered? The code you gave is innocuous, please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you can get this line to output via one of two methods: 1) printf("Test1\n"); (which in certain OSs will not work) or 2) follow the line with fflush( stdout );

Comment: @user3629249, Deduplicator. Thank you, you are correct. I have found it gets stuck when I use pthread_join(), have I not used it correctly?

Comment: @Deduplicator I didnt realize, thanks. I have updated the question and code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to initialize the mutex with `pthread_mutex_init(mutex, NULL);` I am still unsure why it would work with out this for two threads but not more than this?